# Configuring the SSL Certificate for WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm currently trying to configure the SSL certificate for WSO2 and i have a .pfx file for that. I'm following the "**Creating a keystore using an existing certificate**" of [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Creating+New+Keystores) which says to (as per my perception)

- first import/convert your .crt file to .pfx
- then convert/use it as the .jks for WSO2 by executing

> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore < pkcs12 file name >.pfx
>   -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore < JKS name >.jks -deststoretype JKS

Now i've placed my .pfx file into the **< APIM_Home >\repository\resources\security** directory and when i execute the aforementioned command, it gives the following output

[image]

Now, on some of the stackoverflow questions, i've observed the source keystore password as **changeit** which did not work in my case, what could be done here to resolve the issue? Thanks

Comment: Can you try "wso2carbon" as the password?

Comment: Just tried it and got the same error.  @Anuruddha Lanka Liyanarachchi

Comment: apparently you are entering incorrect password of the PFX file

Comment: @gusto2 not really! I just tried that and no luck!

Comment: @AimalKhan the message states the password for the source keystore is incorrect. Without valid password you cannot go further. You should receive the password together with the PFX (p12) file

Comment: @gusto2 the password asked must be of some .jks file and not the .pfx i'm guessing?!

Comment: Have you tried just a simpler keytool command?  just a simple list of the jks contents and try the same password to see if that works?  That would atleast confirm if you do or do not have the ability to access it with that password.

Comment: @jchaplin thanks for your time, i'm actually trying to create a .jks file with this command and specifying the details of a .pfx file in it. Now, i don't really get your answer, what .jks file are you pointing at for access? There's no .jks file in the scenario yet!

Comment: ok I misunderstood slightly.  Then I would suggest creating it separately before importing the .pfx. and then importing it.  See if that has a different result.  Or alternatively using teh wso2carbon keystore, Removing their Keypair and then adding yours to it.  Maybe one of the WSO2 guys could provide us guidance on whether that is a good/bad idea.

Comment: @AimalKhan The first password is asked for the source keystore and that's the pfx file. You should receive the password together with the pfx file.

Comment: @gusto2 The first password is for the DESTINATION key store which is about to be exported/created. I just don't get the idea of the SOURCE key store when there is no such source key store used.

Comment: @jchaplin, For trying the wso2carbon key store, i'll certainly be needing its private key before i could have its .pfx file and .jks file afterwards. You're right, the wso2 guys could guide us in a better way!

Comment: Try using the Portecle tool (https://sourceforge.net/projects/portecle).  It has a nice UI and, in my experience, gives a much better feedback when there is something wrong.